# SQL query to get customers who bought multiple product_types based on the filter

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have data in this format:

| month | country | customer | product_type | product | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jan | portugal | walmart | electronics | laptop | 100 |
| mar | portugal | walmart | electronics | laptop | 120 |
| feb | portugal | walmart | electronics | mobile | 50 |
| jan | portugal | walmart | stationary | pen | 2 |
| mar | portugal | tnt | stationary | pen | 3 |
| mar | portugal | tnt | sports | football | 10 |

How can I get the count of customers who brought two types of product type, say for example I filter by product_type in ('electronics', 'stationary')?

If I do:

```
select count(distinct customer) from price 
where product_type in ('electronics', 'stationary')
```

it will give me the count of all customers bought one of these or both

Instead if I do:

```
select count(distinct customer) 
from price
where product_type in ('electronics', 'stationary')
having count(distinct product_type) = 
  (select count(distinct product_type) 
  from price 
  where product_type in ('electronics', 'stationary'))
```

then this will give me correct result.

But in the frontend, how will I filter by product_type if product_type wont be there in final select above? Sorry if this is confusing but my objective is, when I filter by 1 product_type in frontend, then the query should get me the count of distinct customers who bought 1, if I select two, then it should return the count of distinct customers who bought both products and so on.

Comment: There is no `customer` column on your data, also `product_type` should be `product` ! Please edit your question and include some simple data that is relevant to your attempts !

Comment: @SelVazi sorry, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You can get only customers who have purchased products from 2 different product types by using the `HAVING` clause along with the `CASE` clause:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select customer
  from price
  where product_type in ('electronics', 'stationary')
  group by customer
  having count(distinct product_type) = 2
) as s
```

Dynamically getting total number of product_type on snowflake can be :

```
select count(*) as _count
from (
  select customer
  from price
  where product_type in ('stationary')
  group by customer
  having count(distinct product_type) =
         ARRAY_SIZE(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('stationary'))
) as s;
```

Demo on mysql : https://dbfiddle.uk/ZFzFn445

Comment: thanks for this but this will not work since I cannot change the query like this. So the view I create, I will be using in my front end. So whenever I apply a filter for product_type, the query will run like: select * from view where product_type in ('A') like that.

Comment: Edited my answer can you check ?

Comment: sorry this will also not work. Imagine your query above like a view. If I do select * from your_view where product_type in ('electronics', 'stationary') your code will not work. That is the problem.

Comment: The `VIEW` is not mentioned in your question at all. You must create a follow-up question for this.